# Calculate statistics using linq group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to calculate statistics like below :

> Succeeded : 10
>
> Failed : 10

Below are my tables :

```
public partial class MyProgress
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public int TestPartId { get; set; }
        public virtual TestPart TestPart { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Job
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }
```

Job table contains records like below :

```
Id       StateName
1        Failed
2        Succeeded
```

This is how i am trying to calculate staticstics :

```
var query = from p in context.MyProgress
             join job in context.Jobs on p.TestPartId equals job.Id
             where p.TestPart.Test.RegionId == 100
             group p by new
             {
                   p.TestPartId
             } into g
             select new
             {
                    succeeded = g.Sum(e => g.First(). ? 1 : 0),     
             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But in above query i am unable to get StateName property while calculating Succeeded and Failed stats because i am unable to select in part of group by.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Do you _only_ want the number of failed and succeeded?  Or do you need other information along with that?

Comment: @maccettura Only want number of Failed and Succeeded

Comment: Downvoter please atleast care to comment what is missing in this question so I will keep in mind when posting next question.Thanks :)

Comment: `group by` creates a new object. use p.TestPartId instead: `group p by p.TestPartId` also, if you only have succeeded and failed as states, then maybe use a boolean `HasSucceeded` instead. Or an enum would work too.

Comment: Why does `TestPartId` match `job.Id` and not `JobId`? Why do you need a reference to `MyProgress` to compute total statistics for `Jobs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the results of interest using group by and then count each type in the (one) group:

```
var ans = from p in MyProgress
          where p.TestPart.RegionId == 100
          join j in Jobs on p.TestPartId equals j.Id
          group j by 1 into jg
          select new {
              Succeeded = jg.Count(j => j.StateName == "Succeeded"),
              Failed = jg.Count(j => j.StateName == "Failed")
          };
```

You can also think about it the other way and find the `job`s of interest, but you still need the single group to count:

```
var ans2 = from j in Jobs
           where (from p in MyProgress
                  where p.TestPart.RegionId == 100
                  select p.TestPartId).Contains(j.Id)
           group j by 1 into jg
           select new {
               Succeeded = jg.Count(j => j.StateName == "Succeeded"),
               Failed = jg.Count(j => j.StateName == "Failed")
           };
```

Note: If you are okay with getting a table with each state and a count, you can group on `StateName` instead:

```
var ans3 = from p in MyProgress
           where p.TestPart.RegionId == 100
           join j in Jobs on p.TestPartId equals j.Id
           group j by j.StateName into jg
           select new {
               StateName = jg.Key,
               Count = jg.Count()
           };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me.Appreciated :)